# npm error with module.js 549 Can not find npm-cli.js

Tags: npm

When I reinstalled `nodejs` `npm` can to work, but after entering 3-4 commands in `cmd`  to `npm` like

```
    npm install nw-builder -g
```

it gives out this error

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolceFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (boolstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolceFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (boolstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I had tried to install `npm-cli.js`, but I get (in logs)

```
http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/npx-cli.js 1270ms
```

After reinstalling `nodejs` it happens the same.

How I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please include error text in your question instead of attaching a screenshot.

Comment: Did you miss the word install in the command: `npm install nw-builder -g `?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this in the command line:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

This should work.